# Is it possible to SELECT sqlserver data using WHERE with position?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Normally we use a column to filter a sql sentence

```
SELECT col_id, col_name FROM dataTable WHERE col__id>5
```

It is possible use a position to ORDER: `ORDER BY 1 DESC`

Is it possible use a position to filter?? Something like "this":

```
SELECT col_id, col_name FROM dataTable WHERE #2 LIKE '%Peter%'
```

Comment: Even the use of the position for `order by` has been deprecated; it is no longer in the ANSI standard.

Comment: I did'nt know! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The `WHERE` clause is (logically) evaluated before the `SELECT` list, so it cannot refer to `SELECT` list items by number, as they haven't been numbered yet.

It's possible to do it in the `ORDER BY` as that's evaluated *after* the list of selected columns is evaluated, so you can refer to columns by number (though that's [not recommended](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx#Anchor_2)) or alias.

Also, even if it were possible, it would make your SQL more fragile and harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

**WHERE** Clause run before select clause

here is Logical Query Flow

1. [From]
2. [Where]
3. [Aggregations]
4. [SELECT]
5. [Order By]
6. [Over]
7. [Distinct]
8. [Top]

[FOR EXAMPLE](http://sqlearth.blogspot.in/2015/05/how-sql-select-statement-logically-works.html)

Comment: The `where` clause does not *run* before the `select` clause.  It is logically processed first.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @i TINYINT = 2

SELECT col_id, [col_name]
FROM dataTable
WHERE
    CASE @i
        WHEN 1 THEN col_id
        WHEN 2 THEN [col_name]
    END LIKE '%Peter%'
```